# How to get Descriptor from protobuf FileDescriptorProto?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I have FileDescriptorProto of message and I want to get descriptor from FileDescriptorProto in python. what should I do?

Assuming that `DescriptorPool` can meet this requirement. Another question is, if a message has references to other modules, should the FileDescriptorProto of other modules also be included?

```py
pool = DescriptorPool()
file_descriptor_protos = [ ... ]
for file_descriptor_proto in file_descriptor_protos:
  pool.Add(file_descriptor_proto)
my_message_descriptor = pool.FindMessageTypeByName('some.package.MessageType')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested that `DescriptorPool` can achieve this function, and you need to pass all dependencies `FileDescriptorProto` into the pool.

Be careful with the **order** of addition, you have to add child nodes first, then add parent nodes.

The whole process can be completed by referring to the above example